# I'm using cycles render and I can't figure out how to render the image texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv

I modeled a Desert Eagle, or "Deagle," In the internal render system (Blender Render), and then created a new .blend file, brought the model(s) over and then textured them and added a spare mag and 2 spare bullets to show to a friend.
[image: Shown with colors]

So it looks normal. But when i render it, i get this [image: No Color!]

Anyone know a solution to this? I looked around for around an hour and couldn't find a fix for this issue. i'm pretty new to cycles still so I don't know as much as I know about blender render.

EDIT for Carlo: For the lights it's just a simple 3-Point lighting system using rotated planes with the emission node attached. I would send an image, but sadly my reputation is not above 10 currently so I can't have more than 2 images.

And for the nodetree, I don't think i'm going to be able to send one image for that as there are multiple objects in the image and they each have different node trees. There's nothing too complicated to them, as they all just have the "Image Texture" Node connected to the output node. If you need anything else just let me know what you need.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. So you made the materials in cycles? Could you show their nodetree? What kind of lights your scene has?

Comment: I'm still learning how this entire thing works, so i'm sorry if i seem unhelpful with this. I'm trying my best lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In properties, goto material. And click use nodes if you haven't already.

[image: eData] Then click the circle next to color, and select 'image texture'.

[image: Color] Then use the drop down menu to select your texture, then render, and done.

Comment: Ah, so i had forgotten to us the "Diffuse BDSF" node, and that cause the texture to preview but not render. Thanks for the help!